# jquery not working in IE but works in Chrome and FireFox

Tags: jquery, html, captcha

I use this following program for create Captcha using jquery.It was work fine in **Firefox and Chrome**.But when i execute this into **IE it will not work** which means **I cant move the numbers from one place to another place(can't drag)**.How to solve this?

```
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Jquery Captcha</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.3.2.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/ui.sortable.js"></script>
            <style type="text/css">
                body{
                    background-color: #2daebf;
                }
                form.registration{
                    width:600px;
                    margin: 10px auto;
                    padding:10px;
                    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";   
                }
                form.registration fieldset{
                    background-color:#707070;
                    border:none;
                    padding:10px;
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    -moz-border-radius: 15px;
                    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;                          
                    padding:6px;
                    margin:0px 30px 0px 0px;
                }
                form.registration legend{
                    text-align:left;
                    color:#fff;
                    font-size:14px;
                    padding:0px 4px 15px 4px;
                    margin-left:20px;
                    font-weight:bold;
                }
                form.registration label{
                    font-size: 18px;
                    width:200px;
                    float: left;
                    text-align: right;
                    clear:left;
                    margin:4px 4px 0px 0px;
                    padding:0px;
                    color: #FFF;
                    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
                }
                form.registration input{
                    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
                    font-size: 18px;
                    float:left;
                    width:300px;
                    border:1px solid #cccccc;
                    margin:2px 0px 4px 2px;
                    color:#00abdf;
                    height:26px;
                    padding:3px;
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                }
                form.registration input:focus, form.registration select:focus{
                    background-color:#E0E6FF;
                }
                form.registration select{
                    font-family: "Trebuchet MS";
                    font-size: 20px;
                    float:left;
                    border:1px solid #cccccc;
                    margin:2px 0px 2px 2px;
                    color:#00abdf;
                    height:32px;
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
                }
                .button, .button:visited{
                    float:right;
                    font-weight:bold;
                    display: inline-block; 
                    padding: 5px 10px 6px; 
                    color: #fff; 
                    text-decoration: none;
                    -moz-border-radius: 5px; 
                    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
                    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
                    cursor: pointer;
                    margin-top:95px;
                    margin-right:15px;
                }
                .button:hover{
                    background-color: #007d9a; 
                }
                #sortable {
                    list-style-type: none;
                    margin: 5px 0px 0px 16px;
                    padding: 0;
                }
                #sortable li {
                    margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
                    padding: 1px;
                    float: left;
                    width: 35px;
                    height: 35px;
                    font-size: 20px;
                    text-align: center;
                    line-height:35px;
                    cursor:pointer;
                    -moz-border-radius:5px;
                    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    text-shadow: 0 -1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
                    background:#2daebf url(images/overlay.png) repeat-x scroll 50% 50%;
                    color:#fff;
                    font-weight:normal;
                }
                .captcha_wrap{
                    border:1px solid #fff;
                    -moz-border-radius:10px;
                    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
                    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
                    float:left;
                    height:120px;
                    overflow:auto;
                    width:150px;
                    overflow:hidden;
                    margin:0px 0px 0px 210px;
                    background-color:#fff;
                }
                .captcha{
                    -moz-border-radius:10px;
                    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
                    font-size:12px;
                    color:#BBBBBB;
                    text-align: center;
                    border-bottom:1px solid #CCC;
                    background-color:#fff;
                }
            </style>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                (
                function($){

                    $.fn.shuffle = function() {
                        return this.each(function(){
                            var items = $(this).children();

                            return (items.length)
                                ? $(this).html($.shuffle(items,$(this)))
                            : this;
                        });
                    }

                    $.fn.validate = function() {
                        var res = false;
                        this.each(function(){
                            var arr = $(this).children();
                            res =    ((arr[0].innerHTML=="1")&&
                                (arr[1].innerHTML=="2")&&
                                (arr[2].innerHTML=="3")&&
                                (arr[3].innerHTML=="4")&&
                                (arr[4].innerHTML=="5")&&
                                (arr[5].innerHTML=="6"));
                        });
                        return res;
                    }

                    $.shuffle = function(arr,obj) {
                        for(
                        var j, x, i = arr.length; i;
                        j = parseInt(Math.random() * i),
                        x = arr[--i], arr[i] = arr[j], arr[j] = x
                    );
                        if(arr[0].innerHTML=="1") obj.html($.shuffle(arr,obj))
                        else return arr;
                    }

                })(jQuery);

                $(function() {
                    $("#sortable").sortable();
                    $("#sortable").disableSelection();
                    $('ul').shuffle();

                    $("#formsubmit").click(function(){
                        ($('ul').validate()) ? alert("Correct") : alert("wrong");
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <form class="registration">

                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Let's see if you are a human</legend>
                    <div class="captcha_wrap">
                        <div class="captcha">
                               Drag to order
                        </div>
                        <ul id="sortable">
                            <li class="captchaItem">1</li>
                            <li class="captchaItem">2</li>
                            <li class="captchaItem">3</li>
                            <li class="captchaItem">4</li>
                            <li class="captchaItem">5</li>
                            <li class="captchaItem">6</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <a id="formsubmit" class="button">Register</a>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: jQuery 1.3.2 is ancient. The current version is 1.8.2

Comment: CAPTCHA = `Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart`. The ability to drag&drop is not exclusively human. In fact, computers can drag&drop very well.

Comment: They don't even need to. They just need to overwrite the elements being tested.

Comment: `$(".captchaItem").each(function(i){$(this).html(i+1)})` See? I've broken your captcha.

Comment: Now, should I fix your "captcha" toy, or point you to [the _real_ captcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha)?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code using updated jQuery 1.8.2. It works fine. Only problem I see is that when you drag in IE, especially the last box say 6 over 3, it displays in 3 separate lines, but once dropped they return back in order.